# python dataframe The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to add data to a column from another column only if both columns don't have the same values.

```
...
regex = "|".join(v)
contains_data = df[header].astype(str).str.replace(" ", "") \
                .str.lower().str.contains(regex.lower())
null_data = df[k].isna()
if len(df[contains_data & ~null_data]):
       print(df[[k, header]])

       df.loc[contains_data & ~null_data, k] = df[k] + "," + df[header] if df[k] != df[header] else df[k]
```

This filter `df[contains_data & ~null_data]` outputs the following data:

```
         shipping_tag (k)   Shipping (header)
4        Free shipping      Free shipping
```

Since these are two same values, I want to keep the previous one only.

But I get this error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `df.loc[(contains_data) & (~null_data), k]` I think this is because of this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve what you need (update k when not equal header) is by defining a function for it:

```
def f(x):
     if x['k'] != x['header']: 
        return x['k'] + "," + x['header'] 
     else:
        return x['k']
```

and then applying it to the dataframe under whatever condition you want to do it

```
df['k']=df.apply(lambda x : f(x), axis=1)
```